# Looking to create UINavigationView or UITableView in an existing UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I used the template of a UITabBarController application to create an app and I find my self in a situation I can't solve.  I'm looking to create my last view (viewcontroller4 instance with the FourthViewController class) to actually be a UITableViewController/UITableView/or UINavigationController. I can't really tell which will be best for what I need.

Basically it should an info screen, with a tableview, that you can tap a cell and select a different view (Settings, About the application, Help, Email for Support). Any ideas on how to impliment this? I've tried to substitue a UINavigation controller for the UIViewController listed (viewcontroller4).

below is my appdelegate.m code for reference:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3, *viewController4;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController3 = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController4 = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, viewController4, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you tried to create the `UINavigationController` but it will work fine. After you create your viewControllers, do the following:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINaviagtionController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController3, navController, nil];
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks! Now how do I link this back to work within the xib for FourthViewController? What's currently shown when I run it is the UIView that associated in the File Owner (I think) and the Navigation view, too. Do I need to just declare a IBOutlet for a UINavigationViewController?

Comment: you don't need to change your XIB at all. this example creates the navigation controller programatically. your fourthViewController will remain correctly configured per the XIB. You'll need to write code to push desired view controllers from there.

Comment: So now I can use a TableView within that UIView for Navigation? Also, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: that's correct. no problem, have fun with your app. The Table View Programming Guide and View Controller Programming Guide in Apple's docs will help a lot as well.